# Is there a better way to handle default query params using [FromUri]?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following endpoint which has two query parameters (both optional):

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(List<ResourceResponse>))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetResources([FromUri]ResourceRequest request = null)
        {
            request = request ?? new ResourceRequest();
            var resources = ResourceService.GetResources(request.SiteId, request.ServiceId);
            return Ok(resources);
        }
```

And here is my request object:

```
    public class ResourceRequest
    {
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public int? ClubId { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(null)]
        [FromClubId(nameof(ClubId))]
        public int? SiteId { get; private set; }

        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public Guid? ServiceId { get; set; }
    }
```

This code runs fine, but I need to include `request = request ?? new ResourceRequest();` as the first line to account for the case where there are no query parameters submitted.

**Is there a better way to handle the *no-query-parameters* scenario?  Or is this as good as it gets?**

I need to declare my query params as the `ResourceRequest` class so that I can run Validation Attributes on them.

I can't use `new ResourceRequest()` as my default either because it is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: I think your null coalescing approach is as good as it gets (someone please correct me if I'm wrong). It's the only way I've ever seen it done myself, and that's how I've done it for a long time as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use safe navigation operator (introduced in c# 6) like this:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetResources([FromUri]ResourceRequest request = null)
    {
        var resources = ResourceService.GetResources(request?.SiteId, request?.ServiceId);
        return Ok(resources);
    }
```

The GetResources method will received null if the request is null.

Comment: It's true, this would work but only in the endpoint above where all the default values are null anyway. In other endpoints where the default value might _not_ just be null, it won't initialize fields like `SiteId` and `ServiceId` with those default values, as far as I'm aware.